# How to override spark jars while running spark-submit command in cluster mode? (okhttp3)

Tags: maven, apache-spark, hdfs, dependency-management, spark-submit

There is a conflict of jar in my project and jar in `spark-2.4.0` jars folder. My Retrofit brings `okhttp-3.13.1.jar` (verified in `mvn dependency:tree`), but spark in server has `okhttp-3.8.1.jar`, and I get `NoSuchMethodException`. So, I'm trying to give my jar explicitly to override it.

When I try running `spark-submit` command in `client` mode, it picks up the explicit jar that I have provided. But when I try running the same in `cluster` mode, this fails to override the jar at the worker nodes, and executors use the same old jar of Spark which leads to `NoSuchMethodError`.
My jar is a fat jar but spark jar somehow takes precedence over the same. If I can delete the jars provided by Spark, it would probably work, but I can't as other services may be using it.

Following is my command:

```bash
./spark-submit --class com.myJob \
  --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.ENV=uat \
  --conf spark.driver.memory=12g \
  --conf spark.executor.memory=40g \
  --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=/user/myuser/spark-warehouse \
  --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/home/test/okhttp-3.13.1.jar" \
  --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/test/okhttp-3.13.1.jar" \
  --jars /home/test/okhttp-3.13.1.jar \
  --conf spark.submit.deployMode=cluster \
  --conf spark.yarn.archive=hdfs://namenode/frameworks/spark/spark-2.4.0-archives/spark-2.4.0-archive.zip \
  --conf spark.master=yarn \
  --conf spark.executor.cores=4 \
  --queue public \
  file:///home/mytest/myjar-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

```java
final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(configuration.ApiUrl()) // this throws nosuchmethodexception
                            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(new ObjectMapper()))
                            .build();
```

My `mvn dependency:tree` doesn't indicate any other transitive jars in my jar. And it runs fine in local in IntelliJ as well as with `mvn clean install`.

I even tried providing HDFS path of jars (`hdfs://users/myuser/myjars/okhttp-3.13.1.jar`) with no luck. Can someone shed some light?

I get the following exception if I try both `--conf "spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true" --conf "spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true"`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnSparkHadoopUtil$.<init>(YarnSparkHadoopUtil.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnSparkHadoopUtil$.<clinit>(YarnSparkHadoopUtil.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$1.apply$mcJ$sp(Client.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$1.apply(Client.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$1.apply(Client.scala:81)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.<init>(Client.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1526)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.PriorityPBImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.Priority
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.Priority.newInstance(Priority.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.Priority.<clinit>(Priority.java:34)
    ... 15 more
```

But if I have only `--conf "spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true"`, then it hangs

Comment: Have you tried setting `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true` / `spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true`? Just beware of potentially disastrous side-effects :)

Comment: I tried the mentioned suggestions, and I get another exception. added to the description now.. please check

Comment: Thats what disastrous side-effects look like, especially when you built a fat jar with dependency versions different from target environment.

Comment: Please suggest me some ideas to mitigate the problem ?

Comment: why does jar override work fine in case of client mode even without userClassPathFirst=true but it doesnt work in cluster mode ?

Comment: @Saawan Is the jar placed in below 2 hdfs locations?
/home/test/okhttp-3.13.1.jar
/home/svc_mars_mds/test/okhttp-3.13.1.jar
Why this spark-2.4.0-archive.zip zip is being passed won't the dependent jars be use from cluster nodes itself?

Comment: Why this spark-2.4.0-archive.zip zip is being passed won't the dependent jars be use from cluster nodes itself?  Could you please elaborate ? Are you suggesting this is not required ?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue using maven shade plugin.

[Ignore Spark Cluster Own Jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365013/ignore-spark-cluster-own-jars)

Reference video:

https://youtu.be/WyfHUNnMutg?t=23m1s

I followed answer given here and added the following.
Even in the source code for `SparkSubmit`, you will see jar getting appended to total jar list if we give `--jar`, so it will never override with those options but it will add jar.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit.scala#L644

```xml
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <relocations>
              <relocation>
                <pattern>okio</pattern>
                <shadedPattern>com.shaded.okio</shadedPattern>
              </relocation>
              <relocation>
                <pattern>okhttp3</pattern>
                <shadedPattern>com.shaded.okhttp3</shadedPattern>
              </relocation>
            </relocations>
            <filters>
              <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  <exclude>log4j.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </filter>
            </filters>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```